# In SQLServer, can I select multiple values from one table and for each value returned insert rows into another table?

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

Basically, I have two separate sql statements that I generate on the fly and I want to make them into one statement if at all possible. The goal is select multiple keys from one table and then for each key found in that query do an insert into another table. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Something like this ...

1. select key as key_found from keys where date >= GETDATE()-1
2. Foreach(key_found): insert into message (key, message) values (key_found, "This is a message")

*Remember I don't want to write code loop to do this unless I can do it in SQL. I am generating a SQL statement on the fly that will then just be run by a DBA.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
INSERT INTO message (key, message)
SELECT
    key as key_found 
    , 'This is a message' as message
FROM keys 
WHERE [date] >= DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
```

Comment: Yes, this should get me there. Thank you so much!